# Kafka tumbling window application crash

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-streams

I have implemented a tumbling window of 24 hours(I want daily basis aggregation). I have a spring boot application for that. The issue is that when the application restarts it will create a new window.
So how can we prevent this by create a new window and using the existing on restart?

Comment: That's odd, the state of Kafka streams should be maintained across restarts. Do you confirm the application is using the same application id after the restart?

Comment: yes i have a same application id

Comment: Then something is wrong. A Kafka Streams application is meant to execute in parallel => the typical usage is to have several instances of your application up and running and let them share the traffic among them. As they each start and stop independently, Kafka Streams is making sure the state (i.e. the window in your example) is correctly maintained and handed over. So the situation you describe with just one single instance stopping and restarting is just a special case of that. Without more information it's hard to guess what's getting in the way exactly though.

Comment: So you mean that if I have multiple instances of the application it should work fine right?

Comment: I don't think so. I just meant I don't understand why it's not behaving as expected and I'm not able to help unfortunately. My point about several instances was that, given it's supposed to exactly work like that in distributed mode, then it should also do so with 1 single instance as you do. I don't know why it's not the case, sorry